# PrimeNG Angular2 Accordian module error

Tags: angular, primeng

[image]

I am using prime ng accordian module. I have  properly imported all component and its working. I have created new component but I am getting following error .I have tried looking in ro all modules properly imported or not every thing looks fine any suggestions?
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Accordion!

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably forgot to do it in this format

```
 <p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="">
       test
    </p-accordionTab>

    <p-accordionTab header="">

    </p-accordionTab>

    <p-accordionTab header="">

    </p-accordionTab>
  </p-accordion>
```